# Stop Mongoose to create auto index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create schema in mongoose it create new index in mongodb named _id?

```
 const modelSchema = new Schema({
    uid: { type: Number, required: true },
    content: {
        text: { type: String },
        attachments: [{
            type: { type: String, enum: ['IMAGE', 'VIDEO', 'POLL', 'GOAL', 'POST', 'MILESTONE', 'ARTICLE', 'DOCUMENT', 'AUDIO', 'QUOTE', 'USER', 'TIP', 'URL'] },
            object_id: { type: Number }
        }]
    },
    created: { type: String }
});
```

I am expecting this result:

```
"content" : {
"text" : "hello",
"attachments" : [ 
    {
        "type" : "IMAGE",
        "object_id" : 1
    }
]
```

I am getting this result:

```
"content" : {
"text" : "hello",
"attachments" : [ 
    {
        "type" : "IMAGE",
        "object_id" : 1,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a2664fd6db6672ac43f1823")
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set _id to false to disable auto _id when defining a schema

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: String }, { _id: false });
```

check http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id

Answer (score 0):

mongo will create _id default if you want to use your own override with your value you can set as

```
"_id" : 1
```

ex 
if you insert 
`db.a.insert({"name":"abcd"})` this will create _id default
`db.a.insert({"name":"abcd","_id":1})` this will create and set _id as 1